# LESS: firebug detects an error with watch mode

Tags: javascript, less

FireBug notifies me the following error:

```
TypeError: missing argument 1 when calling function less.watch
less.watch();
```

This is what I include in my HEAD section of webpages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  less = {
           env: "development"
           poll: 1000
         };
  less.watch();
</script>
```

My inspiration derived from this link:

- [LESS 1.3.3, watch mode hogging a lot of CPU in espresso editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364881/less-1-3-3-watch-mode-hogging-a-%20lot-of-cpu-in-espresso-editor)

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma there :)

```
less = {
       env: "development",
       poll: 1000
     };
```

Comment: well, thank you, but it was only a write error... I checked my code and comma after "development" is present.... problem seems to be about less.watch()

Answer (score 0):

You should call `less.watch()` after you loaded the less.js script. Because then the less object is really initiated.

```
<script>
  less = {
           env: "development"
           poll: 1000
         };
</script>

<script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  less.watch();
</script>
```

It is indeed confusing that the config variable has the same name as the instance variable.

You can also temporary enable Watching by appending `#!watch` to the URL.

See the LESS Wiki for more info:
https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/Browser-Options#watch-mode